# Unsupported operand types in

Tags: php

I found this error in the error log file "Unsupported operand types in (and then it shows the directory and file which gave the error)". Then it says on line 28. Line 28 on my PHP page reads:

```
$start      =   ($page -1) * 5;
```

This might not be enough information, but please give feedback on what else I should provide to help me out.

Comment: What are the contents of your variables?

Comment: What type is `$page`?

Comment: It might be the error is somewhere else in the code and PHP just complains about `$start`. Please post 2-3 lines before line 28, and the line where `$page` last gets assigned a value before line 28.

Comment: }
 
 function getScenes($page)
 {
  $total  = 0;
  $pages  = 0;
  $start  = ($page -1) * 5;
  $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT count(iId) as total FROM scenes ");
  $scene  = $query->result();
  $total  = $scene[0]->total;
  if($total)
  {
   $pages  = ceil($total/5);
  }
  $q  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM scenes ORDER BY iId DESC LIMIT $start,5");
  $result  = $q->result();
  if( count($result) )
  {
   return array(
       'pages' => $pages,
       'scenes' => $result
      );
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: Don't post that much code into the comment box; edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `intval` function on the variable `$page`. Also, you may want to check the `$start` variable for a negative value.

Like so:

```
function getScenes($page)
{
    $total = 0;
    $pages = 0;
    $start = (intval($page) - 1) * 5;
    if ($start < 0) {
        $start = 0;
    }
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(iId) as total FROM scenes ");
    $scene = $query->result();
    $total = $scene[0]->total;
    if ($total) {
        $pages = ceil($total / 5);
    }
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM scenes ORDER BY iId DESC LIMIT $start,5");
    $result = $q->result();
    if (count($result)) {
        return array(
            'pages' => $pages,
            'scenes' => $result
        );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```